# 1. e4 e6 2. Nc3 - how should Black respond?

Tags: opening, theory, french-defense

I had White deviate from the French main line in a blitz game by playing:

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e6 2. Nc3
```

Since this line is not discussed in the [Wikipedia article on French defence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Defence) I am thinking that Black may have better options than to simply pursue normal French development with:

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "3"]

1. e4 e6 2. Nc3 d5
```

(which is what I played, it being a blitz game and all)

I was thinking maybe it's worthwhile to respond with:
`2...Bb4`
with the aim of a Bishop-Knight exchange and forcing White to suffer double pawns on the c-file.
Or try the non-committing: `2...Nf6` or `2...Nc6`.

The chess engine XBoard / Fairy-Max 4.8Q with 50 minutes available time for Black (for 40 moves) suggested `2...Be7`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You mean "double pawns on the c file", right?

Comment: @TKR yeap, fixed that.

Comment: Is there a particular line you don't like after 2...d5? Because to me it seems like you'll transpose to one of the mainlines most of the time. I don't like 2...Nf6 at all due to 3.e5, and after 2...Nc6 3.d4, White has an improved version of the French Defense. 2...Bb4 doesn't look bad at all if you are a Winaver player

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very hard to answer this question **without White's next move after you played `d5`.** I bet he tried something like `3.Nf3` or even `3.d3` would not surprise me.

You see, the move `2.Nc3` is not bad-it follows all the opening rules, and is used **only to transpose from one opening into another** or **to dodge certain variations that are unpleasant for White.**

In my opinion, I **assume** that White **did not want to play main lines** of the *French defense* so he tried to trick you to transpose into another opening or another line, the one you do not know.

This is especially useful in blitz games. Your move-`2.d5`-is the best move.

Never fool around with transpositions when you play blitz, always spend **the least amount of time possible** on openings. **Quality blitz games** are won in the middle game or by the expiration of thinking time, not in the opening.

The main point of `2.Nc3` is that **it can not be refuted**, and **it can not give White a bad position.**

White tries to force you to waste **important thinking time** on the opening trying to refute this move. You could play `2.c5` here but why? After `c5` you get *Sicilian defense* which is **not your repertoire against `1.e4` is it?** Therefore, White would achieve his goal-he would transpose into opening **you do not know**-because if you intended to play the *Sicilian defense* at the first place you would respond with `1.c5` not with `1.e6` right?

If `2.Nf6` he can dodge the *French defense* by playing `3.e5!` which might give him a slight opening advantage. If `2.Nc6` with the idea to play `e5` and transpose into favorable version of the *Italian game* then `3.d4` transposes into some sort of *Nimzovich defense* and you are out of your opening in both cases.

On `2.Bb4` White can now go for `3.Nge2!?` with events developing something like this:

```
[fen ""]

1.e4 e6 2.Nc3 Bb4 3.Nge2 d5 4.a3 Ba5 5.d4 dxe4
```

This position is known in the *Winawer French defense*-it is coded as `C15` in the `ECO` and the above is the sideline. This variation is not played with bishop on `a5`, and being unable to find any theoretical resource that mentions this position in *Winawer line* I must conclude that the move `Ba5` in the regular line is bad-which is precisely the goal of White's **altered** move order. In the normal *Winawer* things would go like this:

```
[fen ""]

1.e4 e6 2.d4 d5 3.Nc3 Bb4 4.Nge2 dxe4 5.a3 Bxc3+ ( 5...Be7!? )
```

We can list other moves or possibilities for Black after White plays `2.Nc3`, but let us keep this post short and answer your question:

> 1. e4 e6 2. Nc3 - how should Black respond?

Again, I consider your `d5` to be the strongest move-both for theoretical **and psychological/practical** reasons explained below:

**Do not experiment with transpositions** or you may end up in a position that will very likely be **unfavorable for you.** You can break this rule only if you are **100% sure** that transposition can benefit you. If not then decline it **by staying in your opening.** Most of the time this is the best choice to make and **the most unpleasant one for the side trying to trick you.**

If you have further questions leave a comment and I will reply.

Best regards.

Comment: 3.d3 was indeed White's next move.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus: So obvious :) I do not know if you realize it, but with `d5` you actually won a psychological war. I do not play the *French defense* that often but `c5` should be good for you. Then `Nc6` and then **exchange on `e4`** so he can not transpose into *King's Indian Attack` or something else. He will have to lose a tempo to contest the center with `d4` or else you will have space advantage. Hopefully this helped. Best regards.

Answer (score 6):

Well, let's start by looking at the position

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e6 2.Nc3
```

Why does white play 2.Nc3? Because white gets two options after the standard (!) 2...d5, namely 3.d4 or 3.Nf3 as shown below

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e6 2.Nc3 d5 3.d4 (3.Nf3)
```

In case black wants to aim for a French system position, I would say that 2...d5 is the best option. In case black wants to go for other types of positions, then it is possible to go for a Sicilian system with 2...c5 as well as more independent routes like 2...Bb4, 2...e5. It is also possible to go for some sort of hybrid after 2...Be7 3.Nf3 g5 4.h3 h5, as shown below. What is the objectively best move? Well, I would say that 2...c5 and 2...d5 are equally strong. While 2...Bb4 seems like an interesting option that needs a bit more research. Or just try it for fun and see where it goes!

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e6 2.Nc3 d5 (2...c5) (2...Bb4) (2...e5 3.Nf3 Nc6 4.Bb5 Nd4) (2...Be7 3.Nf3 g5 4.h3 h5)
```

Comment: @bof very good points. 2...e5 does look odd, yet the black knight is still on b8 which offers black the extra option of c7-c6 taking control of the d5-square. Of course, objectively, white should be happy with 2...e5. At the same time, the point is to get a slightly different position from the normal ones and hopefully dribble white off the track. Again, it all depends on the strength of the opponent. Regarding 3...g5 in the 2...Be7 line, the idea is similar to the Morozevich line from Nd2-French with 7...h5. After 4.d4 g4, the Nf3 is driven off and white gets less control over d4 and e5.

Answer (score 1):

People (like myself) who occasionally play 1.Nc3 regard this as a main line and are not unhappy to see it. The book by Keilhack mentioned by @mleonard is excellent (as a general chess book) and points out all the transpositional possibilities that White might try to confuse you with. As a counter to some of the remarks made above, White does not always intend d4. He often plays Bc4 or Bb5 followed by d3. If he decides to play e5, he can support it with f4. Because d4 has not been played, ..c5 has less point. Since Whites QN has no better square than g3, Black can stir up trouble with ..h5, but White has seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

As Black, I'd play 2 ... c5. White has failed to occupy d4 with his second move, so I would try to head off his occupation of that square.

Of course, White may be headed for a more restrained version of the French defense, that is, no e5, and d3 instead of d4, but that gives Black some chance to capture the initiative.

Answer (score 0):

In Harald Keilhack's book "Knight on the Left: 1.Nc3" he discusses the position after 1.e4 e6 2.Nc3 and identifies 2...d5 as the most likely Black response.

A transposition to a Sicilian with 2...c5 is possible. But it seems an odd move order for a 1...e6 player. Why not play 1...c5 instead?

2...Nf6 could lead to a sideline of the Alekhine's Defence after 3.e5
Other options are 2...b6 (Owen's Defence) or 2...Nc6 (when 3.d4 Bb4 is a possibility).

2...Bb4 is a little-studied position and White has a large number of playable moves. These include 3.Nge2, 3.Nf3, 3.g3, 3.d3, 3.a3, 3.Nb5!? and 3.Qg4!?

Here is a sample game: [Gmeinwieser-Bromberger, Bavaria 1999](http://chess-db.com/public/game.jsp?id=1137004095.24626040.72356864)